# Android Action Bar Menu Item Color

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, themes

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I am having no luck getting this to work.
I have an Action Bar in my app which has a white background. As such I want any menu items (including the ...) that appear in the action bar to appear black. But I want the other menu items that appear in the drop down to be white text on a black background. In the below image there should be a menu item visible in the red box, but the text colour is white. I just want to change the text colour of the items in the action bar, but leave the other ones as they are.

[image]

Here is my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
 <style name="customtheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
 <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/customtheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerItem">
<item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/my_rectangle</item>
</style>
 <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
<item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/my_rectangle</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
<style name="customtheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/customtheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="customtheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
<item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: <style name="TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/Yourcolor</item>
</style> modify here

Comment: post your dropdown xml and Java code

Answer (score 0):

Add color in your Dropdownitem Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        **android:textColor="Your Color"**
        android:textSize="17dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```